# java swing gui, Error messages from input from JTextField

Tags: user-interface

I am fairly new to java swing, I am trying to implement a simple ATM machine, the first thing the app asks for is a pin, if the code is incorrect more than 3 times it should terminate. If it is correct, it should continue. With the code I have at the moment it accepts any input as correct, when the default pin should be "1234". this is the code I have relating to what I want to do.

public void updateInstructions() {

```
    statusLabel.setText("Enter Pin");
    pinEntered =inputArea.getText();
    operation = 4;
     }
```

if(e.getSource()==EnterButton)

```
    {

        switch(operation)


            case 4: 
                while (errorCount < 3){
                errorCount++;

                if(!pinEntered.equals(pin)){     
                statusLabel.setText(" Please Enter The Correct Pin");

                }else{
                statusLabel.setText(" Success! your curent balance is "+ currentBalance);

                }

        }
```